# res.send, how to exit after?

Tags: node.js, express

After calling `res.send()`, is there a need to call a return or somehow exit the callback function in order to make sure no further code executes? Like how when calling a header function in PHP, you need to call exit after that to prevent further code from being executed.

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  if(req.headers['x-api-key'] === undefined) {
     res.send({msg: "Goodbye"});
  }
  // other code that should only be processed if it has that header.

});
```

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709802/exit-after-res-send-in-express-js

Comment: That should be `res.send()` not `req.send()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use return:

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  if(req.headers['x-api-key'] === undefined)
    return res.send({msg: "Goodbye"});

  // other code that should only be processed if it has that header.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the node manual:

> The method, response.end(), MUST be called on each response.

Comment: @mscdex is correct.  Please ignore my answer as its less than helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Use always next().

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
     if(req.headers['x-api-key'] === undefined) {
        req.send({msg: "Goodbye"});
        return next();

      }
      // other code that should only be processed if it has that header.

   });
```

Comment: There's no sense in calling next() if you just sent a response.